# How to preview the result of a beforeinput event?

Tags: javascript, validation, dom-events

Does the `beforeinput` event provide a convenient way to preview the result of a proposed modification so that it can be blocked if necessary for validation purposes?

I'm not looking for alternative ways to do input validation; I'm already well-aware of methods involving the `keypress` and `input` events, as well as HTML5 validation, etc.. Right now, I'm specifically looking into the `beforeinput` event to see what it offers.

So far, this is the best I've come up with:

```js
document.getElementById("phone").addEventListener("beforeinput", function(e) {
    if(!/^(\d{0,7}|\d{3}-\d{0,4}|)$/.test(e.target.value + (e.data ?? ""))) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    return;
});
```

```html
<input id="phone">
```

The text field in the above snippet should accept a simple 7-digit phone number with optional dash after the 3rd digit.

Notice that I'm appending the event's `data` property to the input's current value to create a preview of the modified value. This works fine if you only enter input sequentially. But if, for example, you type in all 7 digits and then arrow back to just after the 3rd and try to insert the dash, you can't do it, because the validation assumes you're at the end where a dash would be invalid. Other problems arise if you try to replace or delete a selection.

An accurate preview will be required to solve these problems. Is there a simple way to get one from the `beforeinput` event?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You'd have to get the `selectionStart` and `selectionEnd` to figure out how many characters were removed / replaced / etc, but yeah, pretty simple:

```js
document.getElementById("phone").addEventListener("beforeinput", function(e) {
    const nextVal = 
      e.target.value.substring(0, e.target.selectionStart) +
      (e.data ?? '') +
      e.target.value.substring(e.target.selectionEnd)
    ;
    console.log(nextVal)
    if(!/^(\d{0,7}|\d{3}-?\d{0,4}|)$/.test(nextVal)) {
        e.preventDefault();
    }
    return;
});
```

```html
<input id="phone">
```

Comment: I figured the solution might look something like this, since (afaik) other input events only provide a reference to the target element, not the value. Would've been nice if beforeinput made an exception for the sake of usefulness instead of being so tied to convention. Still, I guess this beats undoing invalid input after entry. I'll accept your answer if no one else has anything to say.

Comment: Very nice solution, worked well for me (with slight modifications) for masking input fields using a directive in Angular without hacky keyboard key checks.

Comment: This worked for me, except when the user presses Delete or Backspace. In that case, you need to look at e.inputType, which will be 'deleteContentForward' or 'deleteContentBackward', respectively. But this was a good starting point!

Comment: I don't think this is reliably possible - specially considering historyundo, historyredo, etc. Even if it's possible, it would be a huge implementation.
Also +1 to @mperktold's comment.